# compare the list and replace worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet ("Dump") with 2 columns "Full name" (AA,BB,CC,etc) and "email address" (123@test.com,321@test.com,etc).

The entire Excel contains 200+ worksheets (named as AA,BB,CC,etc).

I need a VBA script to compare the worksheet name to the column "Full name" in the "Dump" sheet and replace the worksheet name with "email address" only if the worksheet name matches with the "Full name", i.e. replace only if AA(Full Name)=AA(Worksheet name).

I have the code to replace "Full name" with "email address" without validation.

```
Sub replace()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("A2:A5").Value
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Sheets(i + 1).Activate
        Sheets(i).Name = arr(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you :)

Comment: If this is complex, please help me other way. If the validation is true i.e. if AA(Full Name)=AA(Worksheet name), I just need the particular worksheet to be sent as an email.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (not tested):

```
Sub replace()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sh As WorkSheet

    ' Step 1: Create a dictionary that maps names to emails
    For Each cell in Sheets("Dump").Range("A2:A999")
        If cell.value = "" Then Exit For ' no more names
        col.Add cell.Offset(0, 1).value, cell.value
    Next
    ' Step 2: Go through all sheets and rename them
    For Each sh in Sheets
        sh.Activate ' not really necessary, but it gives some visual clue
        On Error Resume Next ' ignore mismatch errors
            sh.Name = col.Item(sh.Name) ' replace name by email
        On Error Goto 0
    Next
End Sub
```

This assumes you have the full names in column A, starting at row 2, and the email addresses in column B.

Comment: this works perfect. Just need to remove the ";" at the bottom 4th line :) Thanks trincot :)

Comment: Great! Indeed, that semi-colon did not belong there. I removed it now. If OK for you, please accept the answer (cf. the flag at the top-left of it).